# How to check if a server requires reboot after disk extension

Tags: disk-usage, reboot

I have a newbie question here.

I'm running  a few servers  on ESXi, some new debians, some old debians, also some new centOS and some old centeOS.

Sometimes I'm required to extend the disk space, but here comes the tricky part. Is there a way to check whether the server will require a reboot after i extend the disk in the ESXi because sometimes, during business days/hours rebooting some of the servers is a thing that i don't want to do.

Thank you in advance guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use LVM to expand drive space you will not need to reboot as long as physical drive space is available.

When you have to add a drive in ESX you only have to rescan the SCSI bus (on the GUEST) to get the drive to show.  (w/o rebooting)

For example in ESX (host) you added a NEW 20G drive /dev/sdb to your server. 
Now on the GUEST you can re-scan the SCSI bus without rebooting to get the drive to show.

This example assumes you only have /dev/sda drive. If you have /dev/sdb already it will show up as the next /dev/sd? device.

> again assume new drive is /dev/sdb/

First get scsi host numbers.

```
#>ls /sys/class/scsi_host
Host0 Host1 Host2
```

Then  rescan the scsi bus with  host2 returned from above. (try Host1 if you cannot find it on Host2)

```
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host2/scan
```

(fdisk should now show additional /dev/sdb partitions)

```
fdisk -l |grep sd
Disk /dev/sdb: 20.7 GB, 10737418240 bytes
```

You can now use LVM to expand the logical volume and xfs_growfs to expand the space.

Comment: So does that mean If I've used LVM during the installation process, I will be able to add disk space without rebooting? Because some of the machines are one that I've installed, but some are not installed by myself.

Comment: yes after the drive is rescanned in the above process you can format it with fdisk as an LVM volume type 8E and then use LVM commands to expand the drive followed by xfs_growfs to format and grow the partition. All with no reboot required. 
 That is a another whole thread though.

Comment: I meant partition it in fdisk  above.